# Laravel 5.4 + Angular 2+ apps api client management

Tags: laravel, angular, rest, frontend, backend

I have a backend from laravel 5.4 and I have 3 front-end apps from angular 2+, my problem is how do I manage my API that only the registered apps are allowed to access my APIs? Do I have to make a registration system for the apps who want to use my API or keep a static list on my CORS?

Comment: I think that is a choice you have to make. If the number of front-end apps don't change often I think I would go for the "static CORS list" option.

Comment: Yes, that's a good answer thanks but my choice would be more of non-static apps to use my API, I have an idea though like instead of static CORS, I would pull it from my records but I've read about client secrets like laravel passport  which somehow confuse and overwhelm me and kept me wondering about best practices, any pieces of advice or suggestions? Thanks!